# Django. Import app module

Tags: python, django, import

I am a Django beginner. I created my project, started one new app. I wrote a model for this app. I did 'syncdb' and 'sql app', everything is okay. But when I am going in to django shell, and try to 'import mysite.myapp' it tells my there's no modules named 'myapp'.

Where could be the problem?

```
maze@debian:~/Dokumenty/djcode/mysite$ python manage.py sql poll
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "poll_poll" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "question" varchar(200) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "poll_choice" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "poll_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "poll_poll" ("id"),
    "choice" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "votes" integer NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

and here importing mysite.poll:

```
>>> import mysite.poll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named poll
```

Thanks for help. Cheers.

Comment: Did you try just importing "poll"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's necessary to include myapp in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py` file. Check if you have done that.

Comment: yes, I've done it. Without it I suppose, the 'manage.py sql poll' won't work.

Comment: I think import poll should do it, if you have created the directories as they should be.

Comment: Yes. This is enough.  But why the version 'mysite.******" doesn't work?

Comment: Because that's how the directory structure is and it depends on where you are starting the shell.